# Different segues going to the same ui view instead of different views

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view with two buttons, each one should perform a different segue and go to a different view but they both go to the same view

I tried to delete and create new segues

Here is the view controller with the two buttons

```swift
import UIKit

class DSViewController: UIViewController {

    var finalTol = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print(finalTol)
        view.layer.cornerRadius=30


    }


   @IBAction func diseaseDone(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "disease", sender: self)
    }


    @IBAction func symptomsDone(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "symptom", sender: self)
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.cornerRadius = 30

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white




        navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        switch (segue.identifier) {
        case "disease":
            let vc = segue.destination as! DiseaseViewController
            vc.finalTol=self.finalTol
        case "symptom":
            let vc = segue.destination as! SymptomViewController
            vc.finalTol = self.finalTol
        default:
            print(finalTol)
        }
    }
}
```

I expect disease to go to diseaseViewController and symptom to go to SymptomViewController but they both go to symptom

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information here to identify the problem.

Have you checked in your storyboard that each button is connected to the correct IBAction and ONLY the correct IBAction? Select your button and check the connections tab to ensure that is the case. You may have set them both to "syptomsDone" or you may have set them to segue in the storyboard instead of calling your IBAction.

Also check your custom segue identifiers to be sure.

Comment: Could you verify the IBAction is being called with a simple print statement inside of it? Look in your storyboard in the view hierarchy and look at the bottom to see the segues. Is there a segue there that you don't expoect?